# Adding event listeners to elements cloned from the template tag

Tags: javascript, html, templates, shadow-dom, documentfragment

I am creating a lot of DOM elements (each has the same HTML structure) with the `<template>` tag:

```
<template id="weapon-template">
    <div class="button">
        <div class="button-price"  data-price ></div>
        <img class="button-image"  data-image >
        <div class="button-name"   data-name  ></div>
        <div class="button-damage" data-damage></div>
        <div class="button-amount" data-amount></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

... and a few lines of JavaScript:

```
var clone;
var template = document.getElementById( "weapon-template" );

template.content.querySelector( "[data-image]"  ).src = data.prev;
template.content.querySelector( "[data-price]"  ).innerHTML = data.cost + "$";
template.content.querySelector( "[data-name]"   ).innerHTML = data.name;
template.content.querySelector( "[data-damage]" ).innerHTML = data.damage;
template.content.querySelector( "[data-amount]" ).innerHTML = 0;

clone = document.importNode( template.content, true )
this.container.appendChild( clone );
```

I would love to add some event listeners on the cloned elements. I could not find nothing from internet and tired a couple of things my self, like:

```
template.content.querySelector( "[data-price]" ).addEventListener( "click", action, false );
clone.querySelector( "[data-price]" ).addEventListener( "click", action, false );
```

... none of these worked. I could simply do something like:

```
var child  = this.container.childNodes[ 0 ];
var target = child.querySelector( "[data-price]" );

target.addEventListener( "click", action, false );
```

... but I wonder if there is another, simpler way similar to those that has not worked for me.

Comment: Why are you selecting by `data-*` attributes?

Comment: @Jamen Simply because I don't want any id duplicates.

Comment: @Jamen Class names can change at any time, for example when I'll design some new buttons and with a different HTML structure, etc. In this case `data-*` attributes are juste like id's, so I can separate the JS functionality from the CSS design.

Comment: I think `name` would be a more semantic attribute for, well, _naming_ elements in a template.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding event listener on a dom element inside template tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387346/adding-event-listener-on-a-dom-element-inside-template-tag)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Until you 'activate' template using document.importNode, its content are inert nodes which are not part of DOM.

As per addEventListener docs:

> The event target may be an Element in a document, the Document itself,
>   a Window, or any other object that supports events (such as
>   XMLHttpRequest).

Therefore adding event listeners in your example won't work until you clone template contents **and** add them to an existing node in document.

If you are ready to use jQuery, there is a workaround. You can use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using jquery on method to bind events to parent element.

something like this:

```
$(this.container).on('click', '[data-price]', action);
```

What this will essentially do that any click which is being triggered from children of `this.container` will bubble up till parent. If it satisfies the selector criteria of `[data-price]` action will triggered on it.

Comment: You can add event listeners to the clone before adding them to the DOM e.g. `clone.firstElementChild.addEventListener` which I've been using a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you can get around using a  for your list rows, then your document.getElementById(...) will return an actual DOM element instead of just the DocumentFragment that it does right now. This means that importNode(...) will return you real DOM nodes on which you can call addEventListener and hook up events!