# adding event listener on a dom element inside template tag

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have button inside a template

```
<template id="persons">
     <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td><button type="button" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
     </tr>
</template>
```

Now im trying to add an event listener to the button by

```
this.oBtnDel = document.getElementById('delete');

this.oBtnDel.addEventListener("click", somefunc);
```

however im getting an error saying

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

how can i fix this?

Comment: This means that the button is not rendered yet. You can look into delegates instead'

Comment: Is the button element available in the `DOM` at the time of adding the listener?

Comment: Are you planning on adding that button to the DOM? You should try attaching the event handler after that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Items in templates are not part of the regular DOM. They will not be there when you are binding the event listener. You will also have a problem with `id="delete"` if you have more than one as Ids must be unique.

What you need to do is use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture), and I will use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to identify the button.

**Template**

```
<template id="persons">
     <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td><button type="button" data-action="delete" data-objectid="id to delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
     </tr>
</template>
```

**Javascript**

```
//Bind the event to the parent table say it has an id of parentTable
this.oTable= document.getElementById('parentTable');    
this.oTable.addEventListener("click", function(event){
   //check the delete button was clicked
   if(event.target.dataset.action === "delete")
   {
       //Logic for delete goes here
       var idToDelete = event.target.dataset.objectid;
       /*Rest of your logic*/
   }
});
```

**NOTE** the code above is untested. If it doesn't work, you should be able to fill in the gaps with the links provided.

Further reading on event delegation: https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: sir can i ask this part ? if(event.target.dataset.delete == "delete") should this be change to if(event.target.dataset.action== "delete") ?

Comment: Correct, well spotted! Must be time for my afternoon coffe.

Comment: why im i getting null in the event.target.dataset.objectid i just append the attribute just like this oCRUD.oTd[5].setAttribute("data-objectid", element.id); on the getPerson() and suddenly im getting null

Comment: Data attributes are a little different to regular attributes you'd be better off with `oCRUD.oTd[5].dataset.objectid = element.id;`

Comment: still im getting undefined when i console.log(event.target.dataset) im just getting the DOMStringMap {action: "delete"}action: "delete"__proto__: DOMStringMap there is no value for the objectid

Comment: but when i inspect element <td data-objectid="1"><button type="button" data-action="delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td> the data-objectid is already define?

Comment: Ahh I missed something, you're applying the data attribute to the `td` not the button. To apply it to the button try `oCRUD.oTd[5].querySelector("[data-action=delete]").dataset = element.id`

Answer (score 2):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template),

> The HTML Content Template (`<template>`) element is a mechanism for holding HTML that is not to be rendered immediately when a page is loaded but may be instantiated subsequently during runtime using JavaScript.
>
> Think of a template as a content fragment that is being stored for subsequent use in the document. While the parser does process the contents of the `<template>` element while loading the page, it does so only to ensure that those contents are valid; **the element's contents are not rendered**, however.

The contents of `<template>` are not yet rendered when you are trying to attach an event handler to the button. Try attaching the event handler after including the template to an element.

See the snippet below:

```js
var template = document.getElementById("persons");
document.body.appendChild(template.content);

this.oBtnDel = document.getElementById('delete');
this.oBtnDel.addEventListener("click", () => console.log("click"));
```

```html
<template id="persons">
     <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td><button type="button" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
     </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: sir can you look at my whole code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386589/refresh-table-after-a-successful-axios-post-request?noredirect=1#comment101256726_57386589

Answer (score -1):

Try like this.

```
 <script> 
        document.getElementById("delete").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
        // Write your function here
    }); 
        </script>
```